# "Autistic thinking"

Tags: word-usage

I'm currently editing a transcribed lecture and came across the phrase "autistic thinking". The lecture is about education, and the phrase was used outside the context of psychiatry. I think what the speaker meant to say (the speaker isn't a native speaker of English) was something akin to "self-centric" or even "narrow-minded". My question is, do you think his use of this phrase is offensive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this related to vaccines?

Comment: It sounds like he simply used the wrong word.  (Perhaps spell check picked it for him?)

Comment: I would be offended if you described *me* or any of my actions as being the result of a genetic mental handicap from which I do not suffer. And I suspect, so would anyone who's actually autistic; being an idiot doesn't count you into the special needs club. Of course if we're talking about the *altruistic* capabilities of people with autism, then I've got it all wrong.

Comment: Can you give the context (the surrounding sentence/paragraph) of the transcribed lecture? Otherwise we have absolutely no idea if the author is being metaphorical or literal or using the wrong word.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not a typo. Here's some context:
"Education is crucial. People think that education is a way to ensure their kids a nice future; that is autistic thinking, just to think that I exist, my family exists, and nothing else matters."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Hotlicks; *autistic* is not the original word. I had to do a double take to see that it wasn't the word:

**altruistic** [al-troo-is-tik] adjective -[TFD](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non-altruistic)

> 1. unselfishly concerned for or devoted to the welfare of others (opposed to egoistic).
> 2. Animal Behavior. of or relating to behavior by an animal that may be to its disadvantage but that benefits others of its kind, often its close relatives.

**Altruistic Thinking** -[blog.pdus2go.com](http://blog.pdus2go.com/special-edition/altruistic-thinking-look-outside-yourself/)

> The Altruistic Thinking style is characterized by a concern for others and a deep value for relationships.

*Nonaltruistic* would be the reverse. Given the context "self-centric" and "narrow-minded" within the realm of psychiatry, nothing else would make sense.

Comment: Let me congratulate you. +1.

Comment: *Altruism* should be the Stack Exchange word of the day, every day.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he didn't mean "altruistic". Here's the phrase in context:
 
"Education is crucial. People think that education is a way to ensure their kids a nice future; that is autistic thinking, just to think that I exist, my family exists, and nothing else matters."

Comment: Please read this [other answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/234031/1746) also by @Mazura, which they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

No, not offensive but used in the wrong context.  There is nothing shameful about being an autist or having an autistic mentality or behavior, but the word shouldn't be used to refer to people whose mentality one dislikes, such as egocentric or narrow-minded.

Answer (score 1):

**Autistic** au·tis·tic (aw-tis'tik), -[TFD](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/autistic)

> 1. Pertaining to or characterized by autism.
> 2. **A psychological term for an extreme narrowing of relationships to people and the larger world.**

**Autistic thinking** -[Glossary of psychiatry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_psychiatry), Wiki

> Autistic thinking is a term used to refer to thinking not in accordance with consensus reality that emphasizes preoccupation with inner experience. See also:
>
> Dereistic Thinking: An old descriptive term used to refer to thinking not in accordance with the facts of reality and experience and following illogical, idiosyncratic reasoning. This term is also used interchangeably with autistic thinking though not an exact synonym. Dereistic emphasizes disconnection from reality and autistic emphasizes preoccupation with inner experience.

Your question asks if the following sentence would be offensive, if we re-replace the bracketed text with "*that is autistic thinking*":

> Education being crucial, people think that it's a way to ensure their kids a nice future, [however it purports an extreme narrowing of relationships to people and the larger world], just to think that I exist, my family exists, and nothing else matters.

In the context of psychiatry (the phrase doesn't seem to exist outside of it) I don't see how either rendition would be offensive. However, as nearly every first definition I came across for *autistic* was "*pertaining to or characterized by **autism***" I am beginning to understand why so many also thought spell-check the culprit. Although I heartily disagree with its use, it *is* a given psychiatric term; no offense was intended, nor will any be received (by his peers).

TL:DR

Is it offensive in the context? NO.
Is it the correct nomenclature? YES.
IMO- Should you ever use *autistic* as an adjective to describe anyone, or their actions, of those who **do not** suffer from autism? NO. (only psychiatry gets a pass on this)

Comment: -Leaving my previously assumed, *wrong* answer for reference, I thought it best to start from scratch given this new context. -Of note, my mother has a masters in Spec Ed; she was *not* on board with this and agrees with my opinion (granted, that's not a degree in psych...).